# Selenium - take data from highcharts

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to ask, if is there a way to take `text` from elements in this `tooltip` with selenium? `highcharts` [image]
I would like to have that: `46` value.
Btw. sorry for japanese

Comment: Refer this https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5479/selenium-webdriver-and-highchart-testing and https://github.com/Ardesco/Powder-Monkey/blob/master/src/test/java/com/lazerycode/selenium/charts/HighChartsIT.java It won't be easy

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried to let selenium mouseover the element and then just fetch it like any other text value from a html-element?

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium using java script executor you can get some data values that are shown in the tooltip of highcharts & not exactly tooltip text  . Just try below script in browser console to get correct properties for '46' value.

Below is java script that can be used to get data on the y axis for 'Manufacturing' in line chart https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic

```
var chart = document.querySelector('#container');Highcharts.charts[chart .getAttribute('data-highcharts-chart')].series[1].yData
```

It will give below output. These are same value shown in tooltips.

```
 [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
```